# Python - How do I make a window along with widgets without using modules like Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have been wanting to know how to make a GUI without using a module on Python, I have looked into GUI's in Python but everything leads to Tkinter or other Python GUI modules. The reason I do not want to use Tkinter is because I want to understand how to do it myself. I have looked at the Tkinter modules files but it imports like 4 other Modules.

I don't mind the modules like system, os or math just not modules which I will use and not understand. If you do decide to answer my question please include as much detail and information on the matter. Thanks -- Darrian Penman

Comment: Well, it's not possible to program GUI in pure python, it would require Tcl and a lot of low-level c to get an equivalent GUI framework. Python _tkinter module is just a binding to the underlying tk framework. Without knowing C, there's not much that you will be able to grasp from its source either, so if you wish to make GUI's, Tkinter should be a good starting point with python.

Comment: A GUI requires low-level code that just isn't possible to write in pure Python. At the very least, you would need to write C extensions that interacts with the interface provided by your OS or desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write a GUI in Python without importing either a GUI module or importing ctypes.  The latter would require calling OS-specific graphics primitives, and would be far worse than doing the same thing in C.  (EDIT: see Roland comment below for X11 systems.)

The python-coded tkinter mainly imports the C-coded _tkinter, which interfaces to the tcl- and C- coded tk GUI package.  There are separate versions of tcl/tk for Windows, *nix, and MacOS.

Comment: You *could* use `struct` and `socket` to "speak" raw X11 protocol. Provided you are a glutton for punishment. :-)  I've used Xlib and Athena from C, which isn't exactly a joy. But this would be much worse. Not exactly Pythonic either...

Comment: @RolandSmith: that would be one heck of a challenge! No doubt, somebody somewhere has probably done it.

Comment: @BryanOakley [looks like it](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib). IMHO, they did a pretty good job of making it a Python library instead of a C library in Python. It might benefit from using modern Python features such as `Enum`, but otherwise I'd say "well done".  Not enough to tempt me to ditch modern toolkits and go back to writing GUI's in Xlib, though!

Comment: @RolandSmith: some people have waaaaay too much spare time :-)

Comment: @RolandSmith I referenced your addition, which I did not know about, in an edit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that you can't write to a database without using a database module, you can't create GUIs without a GUI module. There simply is no way to draw directly on the screen in a cross-platform way without a module.

Writing GUIs is very complex. These modules exist to reduce the complexity.